# rewrite mod is not working correctly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to have 1 variable or sometimes 2 variables in my url.

```
http://example.com/home
or http://example.com/home/hr
```

I created the following `.htaccess` file in `public_html` folder:

```
 RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 ReWriteRule
 ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/? index.php?page=$1&q=$2
```

It's not working! I do have `index.php` in `public_html` and `hr.php` in `public_html/view`

now `hr.php` is included in `index.php`:

```
include("view/hr.php")
```

so now `index.php` has page variable and `/view/hr.php` has the 2nd variable.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your logic in the `.htaccess`, rewrite everything except your static files to one php file, then route your requests inside that. E.g.:

```
# only rewrite static file URLs when not found, otherwise let them through 
RewriteCond $0 !^(?:js|css|img|video|audio)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ^[^/]+ index.php
```

Now, in `index.php`, you have the URL in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and you can include any file you want.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is `index.php` being called at all? Did you ensure `RewriteEngine` is `On`? did you check the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?